# How to get top 'n' CPU consuming processes in particular time interval by performance monitor or any other utility?

Tags: windows, system-administration, process-management, process-control, process-monitoring

I am using windows 2000 server. I want to know top 5 processes that consume most CPU at particular time.

I am using performance monitor for this purpose. But the problem is in performance monitor tool I can add specific process and records in CPU utilization , **but I cannot find at particular time which random process is consuming highest CPU**.

Can I find this with performance monitor or some other utility ?

Comment: I cann't understand y negative remark for this ques.. I think today's programming world CPU utilization of any application is a important part of it... Kindly do mention the reason of negative remark.. it would help other users also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResLoad Notifier.. is the tool I am searching for.

It notifies you about the process, if that process consume CPU more than threshold value that you set.